# Creating dataframe with all jumbled combinations from previous dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
John
Kelly
Jay
Max
Kert
```

I want to create new dataframe such that the output is as follows:

```
John_John
John_Kelly
John_Jay
John_Max
John_Kert
Kelly_John
Kelly_Kelly
Kelly_Jay
Kelly_Max
Kelly_Kert
...
Kert_Max
Kert_Kert
```

Comment: Hi there, you need to follow the guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. SO is not a free coding provider, you need to show your work. You need to add code showing what you did and what is failing.

Comment: @DPM ok I will add my code and follow these guidelines

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "name" the column, you can use a cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df2 = df.merge(df, how='cross')
out = (df2['name_x']+'_'+df2['name_y']).to_frame('name')
```

Or, with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
out = pd.DataFrame({'name': [f'{a}_{b}' for a,b in product(df['name'], repeat=2)]})
```

output:

```
           name
0     John_John
1    John_Kelly
2      John_Jay
3      John_Max
4     John_Kert
5    Kelly_John
6   Kelly_Kelly
7     Kelly_Jay
8     Kelly_Max
9    Kelly_Kert
10     Jay_John
11    Jay_Kelly
12      Jay_Jay
13      Jay_Max
14     Jay_Kert
15     Max_John
16    Max_Kelly
17      Max_Jay
18      Max_Max
19     Max_Kert
20    Kert_John
21   Kert_Kelly
22     Kert_Jay
23     Kert_Max
24    Kert_Kert
```

Comment: @sammywemmy but slower no?